# how to merge sql table with different ID

Tags: mysql, join, merge

How to merge thos 2 tables 
I have these 2 tables:
Table1

```
ID      first_name      laste_name      colum1
1       John            Smith           CD
2       Foo             Bar             CD
3       Jean            Bon             CD
10      Super           Man             CD
11      Bat             Man             CD
12      Mr.             Green           CD
```

Table2

```
ID      first_name      laste_name      colum2
1       John            Smith           MAG
2       Foo             Bar             MAG
3       Jean            Bon             MAG
4       James           Bond            MAG
5       Iron            Man             MAG
6       Sandra          Bullock         MAG
```

I would like to have this result:

Table3

```
ID      first_name      laste_name      colum1      colum2
1       John            Smith           CD          MAG
2       Foo             Bar             CD          MAG
3       Jean            Bon             CD          MAG
4       James           Bond                        MAG
5       Iron            Man                         MAG
6       Sandra          Bullock                     MAG
10      Super           Man             CD
11      Bat             Man             CD
12      Mr.             Green           CD
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin with mysql!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving example using `mysql` syntax.

```
SELECT ifnull(A.Id,B.Id) ID,
   ifnull(A.Ifirst_name,B.first_name) AS first_name,   
   ifnull(A.laste_name,B.laste_name) AS laste_name, 
   A.Column1,b.Column2 
from Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B on A.Id = B.Id

UNION ALL

SELECT ifnull(A.Id,B.Id) ID,
   ifnull(A.Ifirst_name,B.first_name) AS first_name,   
   ifnull(A.laste_name,B.laste_name) AS laste_name, 
   A.Column1,b.Column2 
from Table1 A RIGHT JOIN Table2 B on A.Id = B.Id
```

Comment: I am using mysql !!! this does not work

Comment: I changed my answer. You cannot use full outer join in mysql. It can be achived using left join and right join

Comment: YESSSSSSS !!!!!!
just some syntax error : b.Id -> B.Id TableB -> Table2 B